# Assign TWO Images to Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, radio-button

Hi so I have this "product" [page](https://jsfiddle.net/h3o5bdmf/2/) `(on Fiddle)` where I have multiple radio boxes in two classes .choosesize and .choosetea. I want to set up my code where if the 8oz radio button is selected then one set of pictures will appear for all the tea selections and if the 16oz radio button is selected another set of pictures will appear for the tea selections.

I have assigned the small and big images to each tea option but I do not know how to show the small pictures if the small 8oz option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't have all the "combined" images, I have added a possible solution.

```
  var size = "small"
  var teatype = "green"

  $('.choosetea input').on('click', function() {
    teatype = $(this).attr('data-image');
    console.log(size + "_" +teatype)
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.columnleft img[data-image = ' + size + "_" +teatype + ']').addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.choosesize input').on('click', function() {
    size = $(this).attr('data-image');

    console.log(size + "_" +teatype)
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.columnleft img[data-image = ' + size + "_" +teatype + ']').addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

So this will comebine `size` and `teatype`, So each image will have the data-image where it should be `size_teatype`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var size = "small"
  var teatype = ""

  $('.choosetea input').on('click', function() {
    teatype = "_"+$(this).attr('data-image');
    console.log(size  +teatype)
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.columnleft img[data-image = ' + size  +teatype + ']').addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.choosesize input').on('click', function() {
    size = $(this).attr('data-image');

    console.log(size  +teatype)
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.columnleft img[data-image = ' + size  +teatype + ']').addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });




  //local storage color



  //local storage size





  // add the value of the added radio boxes in the text box
  $('.radios1').change(function(e) {
    var selectedValue = parseInt($(this).val());
    selectedValue += parseInt($(".radios2").val());
    $('#amount').val('$' + selectedValue)

  });

  //add to cart

});



const sizeSelector = 'input:radio[id=small]';
const colorSelector = 'input:radio[id=green]';
const cartSelector = 'button[name=cart]';

$(function() {

  $(`${cartSelector}`).click(() => {
    validityCheck();
  });



  const SMALL = 20;
  const GREEN = 0;
  const CARTBUTTON = 5;

  function validityCheck() {
    let $size = $(`${sizeSelector}`);
    let $color = $(`${colorSelector}`);

    let size_flag = $size.is(':checked');
    let color_flag = $color.is(':checked');

    $('#itemdv1A').toggle(size_flag && color_flag) && $('#itemdv2A').toggle(size_flag && color_flag) && $('#yourbutton').toggle(size_flag && color_flag);

  }

});






const sizeSelector1 = 'input:radio[id=small]';
const colorSelector1 = 'input:radio[id=chamomile]';
const cartSelector1 = 'button[name=cart]';

$(function() {

  $(`${cartSelector}`).click(() => {
    validityCheck();
  });




  const CHAMOMILE = 1;


  function validityCheck() {
    let $size1 = $(`${sizeSelector1}`);
    let $color1 = $(`${colorSelector1}`);

    let size_flag1 = $size1.is(':checked');
    let color_flag1 = $color1.is(':checked');

    $('#itemdv1B').toggle(size_flag1 && color_flag1) && $('#itemdv2B').toggle(size_flag1 && color_flag1) && $('#yourbutton').toggle(size_flag1 && color_flag1)
  };

});


const sizeSelector2 = 'input:radio[id=small]';
const colorSelector2 = 'input:radio[id=oolong]';
const cartSelector2 = 'button[name=cart]';

$(function() {

  $(`${cartSelector}`).click(() => {
    validityCheck();
  });




  const OOLONG = 2;


  function validityCheck() {
    let $size2 = $(`${sizeSelector2}`);
    let $color2 = $(`${colorSelector2}`);

    let size_flag2 = $size2.is(':checked');
    let color_flag2 = $color2.is(':checked');

    $('#itemdv1C').toggle(size_flag2 && color_flag2) && $('#itemdv2C').toggle(size_flag2 && color_flag2) && $('#yourbutton').toggle(size_flag2 && color_flag2);

  }

});






document.querySelector('#yourbutton').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('#itemscart').style.display = "none"
};
```

```css
/* Basic Styling */

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Columns */

.columnleft {
  width: 220%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.columnright {
  width: 120%;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: block;
}


/* Left Column */

.columnleft img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.columnleft img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Product Description */

.product-description {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Product Color */

.tea-type {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.choosetea div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.label {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 9px;
}

.choosetea input {
  display: none;
}

.choosetea input+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.choosetea input+label span {
  border: 4px solid RGB(94, 94, 76)
}

.choosetea input#green+label span {
  background-color: #90978b;
}

.choosetea input#chamomile+label span {
  background-color: #ffd4a1;
}

.choosetea input#oolong+label span {
  background-color: #948e9e;
}

.choosetea input:checked+label span {
  background-image: url(check-icn.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


/* SIZE */

.tea-type {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.choosesize div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.label {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 9px;
}

.choosesize input {
  display: none;
}

.choosesize input+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.choosesize input+label span {
  border: 4px solid RGB(94, 94, 76)
}

.choosesize input#small+label span {
  background-color: #252525;
}

.choosesize input#big+label span {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.choosesize input:checked+label span {
  background-image: url(https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/check-icn.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Product Price */

.product-price {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-price span {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #43474D;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.cart-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: RGB(94, 94, 76);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cart-btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.cart-btn2 {
  background-color: RGB(94, 94, 76);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  transition: all .5s;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#amount {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px solid RGB(94, 94, 76);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: RGB(94, 94, 76);
  width: 55px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#shoppingcart {
  width: 360px;
  height: 300px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.item {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px solid RGB(94, 94, 76);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: RGB(94, 94, 76);
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
  float: left;
}

.item1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px solid RGB(94, 94, 76);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: RGB(94, 94, 76);
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--close all header portion-->
<div class="container">

  <!-- Left Column---Tea Images -->
  <div class="columnleft">
    <img data-image="oolong" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/oolongbig.png" alt=" Big Oolong Can">
    <img data-image="chamomile" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/chamomilebig.png" alt="Big Chamomile Can">
    <img data-image="green" class="active" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/greenteabig.png" alt="Big Green Tea Can">
    <img data-image="small" class="active" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/foliasmall.png" alt="Small Example Can">
    <img data-image="big" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/foliabig.png" alt="Big Example Can">

    <img data-image="small_chamomile" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/chamomilesmall.png" alt="Small Chamomile Can">
    <img data-image="small_oolong" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/oolongsmall.png" alt="Small Oolong Can">
    <img data-image="small_green" src="https://noychat.github.io/Folia-Website/greenteasmall.png" alt="Small Green Tea Can">


  </div>


  <!-- Right Column -->
  <div class="columnright">

    <!-- Product Description -->
    <div class="product-description">
      <span>Folia Tea Collection</span>
      <h1>Signature Teas</h1>
      <p>We source our tea leaves from around the world. Try our many selections of teas and you will taste the difference.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Product Configuration -->
    <div class="product-configuration">



      <!-- Tea Size -->
      <div class="tea-type">
        <h3>Size</h3>

        <div class="choosesize">
          <div>
            <input data-image="small" type="radio" id="small" name="size" value="20" class="radios1">
            <label for="small"><span></span></label>
            <div class="label">8 oz</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input data-image="big" type="radio" id="big" name="size" value="40" class="radios1">
            <label for="big"><span></span></label>
            <div class="label">16 oz</div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--CLOSE TEA Size-->

        <!-- Tea Type -->
        <div class="tea-type">
          <h3>Tea Type</h3>

          <div class="choosetea">
            <div>
              <input data-image="green" data-image1="small_green" type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="0" class="radios2">
              <label for="green"><span></span></label>
              <div class="label">Green Tea</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input data-image="chamomile" data-image1="small_chamomile" type="radio" id="chamomile" name="color" class="radios2" value="1">
              <label for="chamomile"><span></span></label>
              <div class="label">Chamomile Tea</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input data-image="oolong" data-image1="small_oolong" type="radio" id="oolong" name="color" class="radios2" value="2">
              <label for="oolong"><span></span></label>
              <div class="label">Oolong Tea</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--CLOSE TEA TYPE-->



        <h3>Product Pricing</h3>
        <div class="product-price">
          <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
          <button type="button" class="cart-btn" id="cartbutton" name="cart" value="5">Add To Cart!</button>


        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <!--close CONTAINER-->

    <div id="shoppingcart">
      <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
      <h5>Item and Price</h5>
      <div id="itemscart">
        <div id="itemdv1A" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Green Tea"></div>
        <div id="itemdv2A" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item1" value="$20"></div>

        <div id="itemdv1B" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Chamomile Tea"></div>
        <div id="itemdv2B" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item1" value="$20"></div>

        <div id="itemdv1C" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Oolong Tea"></div>
        <div id="itemdv2C" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item1" value="$20"></div>

        <button style="display: none" type="button" class="cart-btn2" id="yourbutton" name="remove" value="10">x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's great! But now when I do this the "big" images are not showing up when I click 16oz then the tea options. Do you know how it could work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nchat I've updated the code a bit, but please remember that IT will only work correct when you have all the images for size and type combined